# Does converge $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^{2}\mu(k)}{\log e_k}$, where $e_k$ is the Sylvester's sequence and $\mu(k)$ the Möbius function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Here is the MathWorld's article dedicated to the so-called [Sylvester's sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersSequence.html). We denote it as $e_k$, for $k\geq 0$.

Let for integers $n\geq 1$ the Möbius function $\mu(n)$, see for example this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html).

I would like to improve this previous deleted question, so I think that is better ask about positive real numbers $R$ for which

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^{R}\mu(k)}{\log e_k}\tag{P}$$
maybe doesn't converge. With this purpose I wondered this question.

> **Question (modified).** Does converge  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^{2}\mu(k)}{\log e_k},\tag{1}$$ where  $e_k$  is the Sylvester's sequence and  $\mu(k)$  the Möbius function?
>   **Many thanks.**

If you want to add in your answer remarks about the problem $(P)$ feel free to do it, or well in comments.

Comment: I've added previous tags, but only is required an easy bound as was said. If it is not possible then provide me hints or details about how one could improve the bound $\frac{1}{2}$ for the absolute value of our series.

Comment: $e_k$ grows so fast that the actual value of the series is $\approx\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{\mu(k)}{e_k}$. The Moebius function is irrelevant, in this context: you can apply the same trivial argument to any bounded function.

Comment: Many thank @JackD'Aurizio I understand your argument.

Comment: Everyone, I believe (for this new version of the question) that with $R=1$ of our problem $(P)$ the series maybe is convergent.